# Как настроить несколько сетевых интерфейсов в Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, netplan

Делаю пет-проект, пришло время публикации и собственно настройки ubuntu. Поднял nginx который слушает порты: 80, 443. Настроил интерфейсы, делал по [инструкции](https://serverspace.ru/support/help/neskolko-setevyh-interfejsov-ubuntu-20/) (поиск в интернете выдавал аналогичные решения). Но что то не получается. Из `ens192` все работает, но из `ens160` приложение не доступно. `ens192` доступен из интернет, `ens160` из локальной сети. Если поменять шлюз, то получается противоположная ситуация. Прошу знающих людей подсказать, что не так.

**/etc/iproute2/rt_tables**

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
50 192
51 160
```

**/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml**

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.10.150/24
      dhcp4: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
      - table: 160
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.10.1
      routing-policy:
      - from: 192.168.10.150/24
        priority: 301
        table: 160
    ens192:
      addresses:
      - XXX.XXX.88.20/29
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: XXX.XXX.88.17
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
      - table: 192
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: XXX.XXX.88.17
      routing-policy:
      - from: XXX.XXX.88.20/29
        priority: 300
        table: 192
  version: 2
```